# input stream function get in c++

Tags: c++

I have a question about the input stream function get in C++. 
Are those the same:

The first one is:

```
ifstream infile ; 

char ch ; 
infile.get(ch);
```

The second one is :

```
int c ; 


ifstream infile ;

c= infile.get();
```

please clarify the difference between these two uses.
Thank you.

Comment: [This `std::istream::get` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) might help you.

Comment: Have you looked at [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)?  What in the docs/examples didn't you understand?  That you're return types are `int` and `char` suggests you're already vaguely aware of the differences....

Answer (score 4):

From: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

> 1) Reads one character and returns it if available. **Otherwise, returns `Traits::eof()` and sets `failbit` and `eofbit`**.
>
> 2) Reads one character and stores it to `ch` if available. **Otherwise, leaves `ch` unmodified and sets `failbit` and `eofbit`.**

In your case, (1) above corresponds to the second block of your code and (2) above corresponds to the first block of your code.

The difference between the two, shown in highlighted text, is what happens to `ch`. In the first case, `Traits::eof()` gets assigned to `ch`. In the second case, `ch` is left unmodified.